# Visual Studio 2008 compiles anything in C++ file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I noticed today that a source code file in a project was compiling even though it had junk at the top of it.  It got me wondering what all would pass without error through the compiler.  Here is an example of code that will not generate any error messages:

```
what kind of weird behaviour is this???

#include "stdafx.h"

// what is up?

int foo(int bar)
{
    bla bla bla?????
    return bar;
}

and more junk???
```

What in the world is the compiler doing to allow this code to compile without giving any error messages?  I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and this is unmanaged C++ code.  The foo function isn't actually generated in the object file so it can't be used but why no errors???

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's being compiled? Perhaps an error-tolerance setting is out of whack somewhere :-)

Answer (score 7):

The part before the `#include "stdafx.h"` line is actually explainable (given that the file is actually compiled): everything before and including that line is ignored if precompiled headers are enabled (which is the default). See [Wikipedia on Precompiled Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header#stdafx.h) for a short summary.

However, if syntactically wrong code below that include is not generating errors it's likely your file isn't getting compiled at all.

Comment: The code was getting compiled.  It was generating a .obj file and I could see the compile happening in the output.  I also was just right clicking on the source file and selecting to compile it so I'm pretty sure it was getting compiled.

Comment: @Brad: Do you mean right-clicking on the source file in the solution explorer?  If so, you might still not be compiling the file you are seeing - you may have dragged in a different file with the same name.  Try this: Close the file you can see and double click on it in the solution explorer to open a real copy, then do some simple but error inducing changes and compile.

Answer (score 4):

It does not compile anything ;)  Your file probably just isn't included in the project.

Comment: There's been many times when i've been working on one file and either a) not included it in the project or b) been working on the file in a seperate project within a solution and didn't have that as the "StartUp" project.

Comment: The file was included in the project.  A .obj file was being generated.  The visual studio build output shows the compiler being run on the source file.

Answer (score 2):

> "The foo function isn't actually generated in the object file so it can't be used"

This should be your hint it's not being compiled. Why would the compiler "compile" something for no output?

Either it's not included, you're looking at the wrong file (technically a variation of the previous), or it has the same name as another source file in the project, in which case only one will be compiled.

Comment: That is what I thought until I checked that there was a .obj file being generated. So the compiler is running on it and generating an output file.  It just doesn't have my function in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I have any suspicions that a file is not being compiled I start inserting:

```
#pragma message("Reached Here!")
```

type lines in the source until I see the message pop up.

I've tested the source code from the OP with VS2008 in a project that uses precompiled headers and [bluebrother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587672/visual-studio-2008-compiles-anything-in-c-file/2587716#2587716) is correct that text before the first `#include` is ignored, including `#pragma message`.

Comment: The precompiled headers does sound like it could be the issue.  I will investigate that more!

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably just not being compiled.

OTOH, VC++ would seem to accept this if it was in a template (that is not instantiated)

```
template <class T>
T foo(T bar)
{
    bla bla bla?????
    return bar;
}

int main()
{
}
```